# JPQL Temporary Table with Sybase ASE

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3, jpql

I get a syntax exception from the Sybase ASE 12.5.3. because the #t temp table is passed to the sql server as a parameter. 
If JPQL (Eclipselink in Glassfish 3.1.2) would just leave it like it is it would work. I testet it inside my SQL Editor.

```
String sql =
"select convert(date, remsfSEND) as send, remsID "
+ "into #t "
+ "from prd.REMEMBERSEARCHFOUND "
+ "where remsfSEND is not null "
+ "group by convert(date, remsfSEND), remsID "
+ " \n"
+ "select send, count(*) "
+ "from #t "
+ "group by send ";
Query query = em_local.createNativeQuery(sql);
List<Object []> list = query.getResultList();
List<RememberSearchStatItem> res = new ArrayList<RememberSearchStatItem>();
for (Object [] o : list) {
    res.add(new RememberSearchStatItem((Date)o[0], (Integer)o[1]));
}
return res;



Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Falsche Syntax bei '@p0'.
Error Code: 102
```

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink by default uses the # as a parameter delimiter, which can be changed using the jdbc.parameter-delimiter property:
http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_jdbc_parameter-delimiter.htm